# How to update only attributes that have changed - Spring MVC mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, api, rest, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB and Spring Data Rest to create a REST API which allows GET, POST, PUT and DELETE operations on my MongoDB database and it's all working fine except for the update operations (PUT). It only works if I send the full object in the request body otherwise variables didn't send it in the rquest are null.Can someone guide me to solve this.

```
@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public void update(@Valid @RequestBody Facture facture, @PathVariable("id") String id){
        Optional<Facture> factureData = factureRepository.findById(id);

            facture.setId_facture(id);
            this.factureRepository.save(facture);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try a object comparison library like [javer](https://www.baeldung.com/javers)

Comment: you mean I'll compare
    Diff diff = javers.compare(Olduser, user);

Comment: @Kindth yes, then you'll have the difference map of the old value and the new value